# Image Resizing on Different Browsers

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, browser, resize

I'm trying to make a website and everything works fine on certain browsers like Google Chrome and Safari, but it doesn't work on Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Here's a link to how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQCCL.png
The first image is how it looks in Chrome and Safari. The second link is IE and Firefox.

The HTML is basically a square image wrapped in many borders.

```
 <div> <div> ... <div> <img> </div> ... </div> </div>
```

The CSS has the image and all the divs set to border-radius 100% and also has code along the lines of:

```
 max-width: 574px;
 max-height: 574px;
 display:block; 
 max-height:100%; //repetitive, I know, but I've been frustratingly trying everything that might work
 width:auto; 
 max-width:100%;
 height: auto;
```

I've tried it with max-height, without max-height, with height: 100%, without height: 100%, etc. I've googled this problem countless times and the solutions that work for others don't seem to work for me. I've set html, body {height: 100%} and I've tried .cycle-slide {width:100%;}  and  section img { width: 100% } but those didn't work either.

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/zc3Y8/1/
The code is a little bit different because I'm using Ruby on Rails on Aptana. But this is pretty much how it looks

Comment: A jsfiddle.com example would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different images as link: First one, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGO4M.png and second one, https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AJk9.png

Comment: Yeah, stackoverflow only allows two links in the post, so I put it together to show what it looks like in Chrome/Safari and Firefox/IE

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My website has two circles. The first image ( http://i.imgur.com/BmMOqw0.png) is how it looks in Chrome/Safari and the second image ( http://i.imgur.com/qiICBR4.png ) of the distorted circles is how it looks in Firefox/IE.

Comment: You have an extra </div>

Comment: It still didn't fix my problem when I changed it, but thanks for that catch.

Comment: Seems that padding is breaking your desired behavior. Try to remove the first one (border0), and change the second one (border2) to 1px. It looks better. In addition, I don't know if you know, you don't have styles defined for border1 class.